# How to add condition to framer motion animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I'm new to react and i made three cards and i used framer motion for the animation . i want when i click the one cards the animation start but the animation start on all the three cards **how can i add a condition to framer motion animation ?**

**sandbox link :** https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-microservice-tllp80?file=/src/App.js

**and here is my code**

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { motion, useAnimationControls } from "framer-motion"


export default function App() {
  const [elements,setElements]=useState(['one','two','three'])
  const controls = useAnimationControls()


  return (
    <section className="App">
      {
        elements.map((Element,index)=>(
          <motion.div key={index}  animate={controls} onClick={()=>controls.start({ scale: 2 })}>{Element}</motion.div>
        ))
      }   
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a component that handles the animation control itself and use it on elements map

Here is an example:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { motion, useAnimationControls } from "framer-motion"


const Card = ({index, Element}) => {

  const controls = useAnimationControls()

  return <motion.div key={index}  animate={controls} onClick={()=>controls.start({ scale: 2 })}>{Element}</motion.div>

}


export default function App() {
  const [elements,setElements]=useState(['one','two','three'])
 

  return (
    <section className="App">
      {
        elements.map((Element,index)=><Card index={index} Element={Element}/>)
      }   
    </section>
  );
}
```